# What's the meaning of Args in ScipyOptimizerInterface in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm reading the code provided in one paper. I can't figure out the meaning of `Args` of `tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface` in the code. What do '`maxiter`','`maxfun`','`ftol`','`gtol`','`eps`','`maxls`' represent?

All I know is it's related to `L-BFGS-B` optimizer. So far, I haven't found any explanation about `Args` of `tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface` even in tensor flow API.

```py
# L-BFGS-B optimizer via scipy
optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(cost, options={'maxiter': 50000,'maxfun': 50000,'ftol': 1e-15,'gtol' : 1e-11,'eps' : 1e-15,'maxls' : 100})
```

I hope someone can explain the meaning of `Args` of `tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface` for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right... I answered this stupid question myself. After a long and seemingly hopeless period of searching, finally, I happened to find the answer, which I have been eager for for nearly a month. The answer to this question is on the SciPy.org. Search the keywords 'scipy.optimize', choose the 'minimize(method='L-BFGS-B')' and here is the explanation.(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-lbfgsb.html)
[Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wNXT.jpg)